# How to print all Animals using Collection Object

Tags: java, collections

How would I go about printing all `Animals` using a collection object:

```
Collection<Animal> c = animals.values();
```

I have already technically done it using entrySet however this is a more advanced way of doing it which isn't what i needed to do.

**How would I go about Printing all animals using a collection object with a simple `for each loop` Without using `entrySets`?**

Any help or advice on this would be much appreciated, thank you! :)

**Zoo class:**

```
public class MyZoo
{
   private String zooId;
   private int nextAnimalIdNumber;
   private TreeMap<String, Animal> animals;
   private Animal animal;

   public MyZoo(String zooId)
   {
      this.zooId = zooId.trim().substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
      nextAnimalIdNumber = 0;
      animals = new TreeMap<String, Animal>();
   }

   public void addAnimal(Animal animal)
   {
      animals.put(animal.getName(), animal);
      this.animal = animal;
   }

   public void printAllAnimals()
   {
     Collection<Animal> c = animals.values();
   }
}
```

**Animal class:**

```
public class Animal
{
   private String id;
   private String species;
   private String name;

   public Animal(String species, String name, MyZoo owner)
   {
      id = owner.allocateId();
      this.species = species;
      this.name  = name;
   }

   public String getId()
   {
      return id;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   public String getSpecies()
   {
      return species;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return id + "  " + name + ": a " + species;
   }
}
```

Comment: `for (Animal animal : c) System.out.println(animal);`?

Comment: with this it highlights 'c' and says 'cannot find variable c'.

Comment: `c` comes from `Collection<Animal> c` you need to keep this line if use `c`, or look my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop:

```
for (Animal a: animals) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

I'd prefer being more succinct: use a lambda.

```
animals.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `Streams` :

   ```
   public void printAllAnimals(){
       animals.values().stream().forEach(System.out::println); 
   }
   ```
2. Using classic `for each loop`

   ```
   public void printAllAnimals(){
       for (Animal ani: animals.values()) {
           System.out.println(ani);
       }
   }
   ```